# What is the metric of an hyperboloid?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, spheres

The metric of a sphere is given by:

$$ds^2=R^2\left(\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta\ \mathrm d\phi^2\right)$$

The sphere and the hyperboloid are connected like the sine and hyperbolic sine are connected. Does that mean that the metric of a hyperboloid can be obtained by replacing the sine in the formula above with the hyperbolic sine?

Comment: *The* hyperboloid? No. Have you worked it out? What is your parametrization of “the” hyperboloid? And why the hyperbolic geometry tag?

Comment: I just wonder if the metric of the hyperboloid is that of a 2-sphere, but with the sine replaced by a hyperbolic sine.

Comment: Don't guess around, don't mess around with notation. The parametrization you find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid#Parametric_representations) for various flavors of "the" hyperboloid. To derive the metric you remember that it is also called [first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface#First_fundamental_form).

Comment: A special case of the one-surface hyperboloid is treated [here](http://quantum.phys.unm.edu/467-17/hyperboloid.pdf).

Comment: @KurtG. Hey, thanks! That's what I was looking for! The metric is explicitly written in it!